# WeakReference for listeners in Android

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern, weak-references

Last time I use a pattern:

```
interface Listener {
   void happened();
}

class Stuff {

  private ArrayList<WeakReference<Listener>> mListeners = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addListener(Listener listener){
      mListeners.add(new WeakReference<>(listener));
  }

  protected void notifyListeners(){
      int i = 0;
      Listener listener;
      while(i<mListeners.size()){
          listener = mListeners.get(i).get();
          if(listener == null)
              mListeners.remove(i);
          else{
              listener.happened();
              i++;
          }
      }
  }

}
```

I see such way as really convinient, but why so many Android's parts doesn't use some similar? In example, `BroadcastReseiver` should be unregistered mandatory.

Does it have any actual cons?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a weak reference for an interface

Comment: not for an interface, but for implementing classes instances